# How to disable certain dates/hours in DatePicker IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, datepicker

I was wondering if there is anyway to disable a certain day or hour in a DatePicker?

I have looked around and many people suggested "UIControlEventValueChanged", I don't think thats a good idea specially if I have to disable more than 10 hours as users will get frustrated.

Is there any other way to overcome this problem? Also I don't really know what days/hours will be disabled but I receive them from my database.

Even colouring those days a different colour would be good

Comment: This isn't supported. Try using a `UIPickerView` with just the rows you want.

Comment: rmaddy, this probably is what i was looking for this whole time. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `UIDatePicker` only lets you specify a minimum and maximum date.

If you want to use a stock date picker you'd have to set up an IBAction that would move the picker to a different value after the user picked a date in the forbidden range.

Or, as rmaddy suggests, use a standard picker view and custom code, or subclass  `UIPickerView` (e.g. create `MyCustomFunkyDatePickerView`) and have that custom subclass implement the rules you want, either with an array of allowed date ranges or a min, max, and an array of forbidden date ranges.

Comment: Im new to swift and didn't know this was possible. Thank you very much